# Rails, Heroku, Watir: Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, watir, sidekiq

I'm running a rails app that I have deployed to Heroku.  I've installed both buildpacks as required by Watir:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
```

The above pack creates a `GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM` environment config that I in turn use -

Here is my current code for setting up the Watir browser:

```
def browser
  @browser ||= Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, browser_options)
end

def browser_options
  if chromedriver_binary_path.present?
    puts "path was present: #{chromedriver_binary_path}"
    {
      headless: true,
      options: { binary: chromedriver_binary_path },
      switches: [
        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
        '--disable-popup-blocking',
        '--disable-translate',
        '--disable-gpu'
      ]
    }
  else
    {}
  end
end

def chromedriver_binary_path
  ENV['GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM']
end
```

The code above lives within a class that is called from a sidekiq worker (so the code runs in a background job / on my sidekiq dyno).

Whenever this code runs, the following occurs:

```
 2020-10-18T05:51:31.082352+00:00 app[sidekiq.1]: pid=4 tid=2ym8 WARN: Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:9515 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515)
```

For the life of me I am unable to get this to work.  I have spent the last week trudging through stackoverflow posts regarding this topic to no avail. If anyone has any ideas or could offer any advice, I would be more than welcome to try it.

EDIT: I should note that my `puts` statement does output the following path:

```
2020-10-18T05:51:24.599171+00:00 app[sidekiq.1]: path was present: /app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

I also have tried using the `webdrivers` gem and uninstalling the chromedriver buildpack to no avail, as detailed here: https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers/wiki/Heroku-buildpack-google-chrome

Comment: With the webdrivers solution, can you turn on logging: `Webdriver.logger.level = :debug` and `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug` I'd like to make sure that Watir is setting the right things via Selenium and see what webdrivers is erroring with.